# Jquery age verification script on BigCommerce, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have used this same script on other websites and I just can't get it to work with my current project at http://www.torchwoodworks.com/. After delving into the firefox script debugger, it seems to be a problem with cookies.js not loading, as i'm getting a "$.cookie is not a function" error. I know i've had troubles in the past if jquery itself is loaded after this script, but that is not the case. As far as I can tell, it should be working.

Here is my code added to the BigCommerce header:

```
<!--Scripting for age verification, added LM 02/03/15 -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://store-kdukte.mybigcommerce.com/template/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://store-kdukte.mybigcommerce.com/template/js/lightbox_me.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://store-kdukte.mybigcommerce.com/template/js/cookies.js"></script>

        <link rel="StyleSheet" href="http://store-kdukte.mybigcommerce.com/template/js/verify.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
            // Halt! Age identification
            // Includes checking for and setting a cookie with cookies.js
            if(!$.cookie('legal-age')){
                        var date = new Date();
                        var minutes = 30;
                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $('#verify').lightbox_me({
                centered: true,
                closeClick: false,
                closeESC: false,
                overlayCSS: {background: 'black', opacity: 1},
                closeSelector: '.v-yes',
                onClose: function(){
                    $.cookie('legal-age','yes', {domain: 'torchwoodworks.com', path: '/', expires: date});
                }
            });
                 e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
<!--end Scripting for age verification -->
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use $.cookie you need to include [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: I am including a jquery cookie library.

Comment: @imerry213 just because you're including it doesn't mean it is working. I see a ton of JS errors on the page you linked to suggesting that plugins you are using do not work with the version of jQuery you have installed on the site.